# appensinding multiline variable to file bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

i am trying to write a bash script that will configure my phpmyadmin, i want to create the config.inc.php file and append the configuration file to it and the file contain a blowfish secret with this function `$(openssl rand -base64 50)`, it created the file but instead of adding the result of `$(openssl rand -base64 50)`, it added `$(openssl rand -base64 50)` to the file.

Here is the code

```
phpmyadmin_config='
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
$cfg["blowfish_secret"] = "$(openssl rand -base64 50)";
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["auth_type"] = "cookie";
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["host"] = "localhost";
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["compress"] = false;
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["AllowNoPassword"] = false;
$cfg["UploadDir"] = "";
$cfg["SaveDir"] = "";
$cfg["TempDir"] = "/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp";
'
echo -e "$phpmyadmin_config" >> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Please what am i doing wrong,

Comment: You are using double quoutes. You should probably be using [backticks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) or [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using shell *here-doc*:

```
cat<<EOF1 > /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
\$cfg["blowfish_secret"] = "$(openssl rand -base64 50 | tr -d '\n')";
EOF1

cat<<'EOF2' >> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["auth_type"] = "cookie";
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["host"] = "localhost";
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["compress"] = false;
$cfg["Servers"][$i]["AllowNoPassword"] = false;
$cfg["UploadDir"] = "";
$cfg["SaveDir"] = "";
$cfg["TempDir"] = "/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp";
EOF2
```

**You can't expand variables in single quotes.**

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words